# win-x64/node.lib local checksum not match remote

Tags: checksum, node-gyp

[image: Error][image]
I am trying to package an electron application. when i try `npm run publish:win64`, it fails and gives checksum mismatch error.

Windows build tools are installed properlly as shown in the screenshot.

tried `node-gyp install` too.

repo: https://github.com/austonpramodh/ytmdesktop

I have tried the same repo in other pc and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to use yarn instead of npm, as npm has some issues with electron-builder. Using yarn solved all the problems.

The image that I have attached is a screenshot from electron-builder Github page.

[image: electron-builder]